# SharePoint Online App for Documentation

Tags: sharepoint-online

Does anyone know if there is a SharePoint Online App or Plugin that could be leveraged for keeping documentation such as Product Guides or Reference Documentation. Essentially, I am looking for something similar to the Books Module built on Joomla ---> https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/book/overview. If there is something like this that is built for SharePoint Online, please let me know.

Comment: why not a wiki?

Comment: One of the solutions could be a wiki but I'd have to customize SharePoint in order to get it to work. I was trying to prove that a solution like the one referenced above is not available in SharePoint @Mike

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the blog site as you can publish from Word, but it sounds to me like you already made up your mind to use Drupal.

Comment: I am getting away from Drupal and want to use SharePoint but what I am seeing is that I would have to build something custom in SharePoint, which is fine. I just wanted you guys to help me validate that my claim of this type of out of the box solution is not currently available in SharePoint Online.

Comment: The blog site or wiki sites aren't exactly like books, but they can be used in similar fashion.